# How to get absolute document path of a file from collection

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest to get the **absolute path of each documents** which are collected thru xslt collection.

Posted script is able to give the required **absolute path**, but I have used two collections (it may take unnecessary memory to store info of all articles twice, one collection for collecting *info* and other one to collect `document-uri()`s).

**XMLs:**

D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/ABC/Test.xml

```
<article>
  <title>First article</title>
  <tag1>The tag 1</tag1>
  <tag3>The tag 3</tag3>
</article>
```

D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/DEF/Test.xml

```
<article>
  <title>Second article</title>
  <tag2>The tag 2</tag2>
  <tag3>The tag 3</tag3>
</article>
```

and other XMLs....

**XSLT 2.0:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="varDocuments">
    <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')
        [matches(document-uri(.), '2016/([A-z]+)/.*?.xml')]"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="varDocuments1">
    <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')
        [matches(document-uri(.), '2016/([A-z]+)/.*?.xml')]/document-uri(.)"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Table border="1">
        <TR><TH>Position</TH><TH>Title</TH><TH>Tag1</TH><TH>Tag2</TH><TH>Tag3</TH><TH>Tag4</TH><TH>Path</TH></TR>
        <xsl:for-each  select="$varDocuments">
            <xsl:for-each select="article">
                <TR>
                    <xsl:variable name="varPos" select="position()"/>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::tag1)"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::tag2)"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::tag3)"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(descendant::tag4)"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(tokenize($varDocuments1, 'file:/')[position()=$varPos + 1])"/></td>
                </TR>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required result:**

```html
<Table border="1">
   <TR>
      <TH>Position</TH>
      <TH>Title</TH>
      <TH>Tag1</TH>
      <TH>Tag2</TH>
      <TH>Tag3</TH>
      <TH>Tag4</TH>
      <TH>Path</TH>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>First article</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/ABC/Test.xml</td>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Second article</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/DEF/Test.xml</td>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Third article</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/GHI/Test.xml</td>
   </TR>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first suggest to change

```
<xsl:variable name="varDocuments">
    <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')
        [matches(document-uri(.), '2016/([A-z]+)/.*?.xml')]"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

to at least

```
<xsl:variable name="varDocuments" select="collection('file:///D:/DocumentPath/Project-01/2016/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')
        [matches(document-uri(.), '2016/([A-z]+)/.*?.xml')]"/>
```

as there does not seem to be a need to pull in the documents with `collection` and then create an additional copy with `copy-of`.

With that correction, when you process each document with with `<xsl:for-each  select="$varDocuments">`, you can simply there read out the `document-uri(.)` now, as you are processing the documents pulled in and not any copy assembled.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect suggestion Sir, getting the required absolute path, plus one.